# Is there any "public class" or "private class" in C++?

Tags: c++, public, access-modifiers, private-class

I searched it up and found out that there's no such thing as "public class" in C++ but it can be used in Java and C#.
A Youtuber used a public class and the video was about some other topic so they didn't explain it.
Here's the code they typed...
[public class in C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIjeK.png)

I'm confused now so please clarify. Thank you~

Comment: Possibly a CLR extension.   Not standard C++.    If not that, bear in mind that youtubers are not necessarily knowledgeable about C++.

Comment: The confusing MS zombie language is called "C++/CLI" or something like that. It is not C++.

Comment: `__interface` is not a C++ term either

Comment: "A Youtuber used". Switch the channel.

Comment: Check out cppreference.com for a start. And yes, there are public and private classes in C++, but possibly not in the way you expected and not in the way they are in Java or C#, which are different languages anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from CLR. You can read something about it here: [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/walkthrough-compiling-a-cpp-program-that-targets-the-clr-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170)

Microsoft has its own version of C++ designed for Common Language Runtime.

I wouldn't recommend learning it, rather stick to the standard version of C++ unless you work in a very specific, Microsoft environment, and basically you need to use it.

Comment: C++/CLI makes interacting between pure C++ and C#/VB.Net much simpler -- it certainly has it's uses.

Comment: I believe that not only the C++ and C# but most of the languages that can run in CLR like Visual Basic, Pascal, Delphi